# Vertically align Radio Buttons

Tags: html, css, radio-button, alignment

Basically I'm trying to get all of my buttons to align vertically like the first question. I can't understand why I can't get the second question to align properly. I tried different things such as using the vertical-align: middle property but I can't get anything to work

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #48c6ef 0%, #6f86d6 100%);
}

#wrapper {
  padding-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -1%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  background-color: white;
  clear: both;
}

#quiz {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#quiz li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.question {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="quiz">


    <form name="quiz" method="post" name="buttons" id="quiz" onsubmit="return false">
      <li>
        <div class="question">1. How many continents are there?</div>
      </li>
      <input id="answer" type="radio" name="group1" value="wrong"> 6<br>
      <input id="answer" type="radio" name="group1" value="wrong"> 8<br>
      <input id="answer" type="radio" name="group1" value="correct"> 7<br>
      <input id="answer" type="radio" name="group1" value="wrong"> 5
      <hr>


      <li>
        <div class="question">2. Where is France located?</div>
      </li>
      <input id="answer" type="radio" name="group2" value="correct">Europe<br>
      <input id="answer" type="radio" name="group2" value="wrong">Asia<br>
      <input id="answer" type="radio" name="group2" value="wrong">Antarctica<br>
      <input id="answer" type="radio" name="group2" value="wrong">North America
      <hr>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `text-align: left;` with `display: inline-block;` solved your problem

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #48c6ef 0%, #6f86d6 100%);
}

#wrapper {
  padding-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -1%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  background-color: white;
  clear: both;
}

#quiz {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#quiz li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.question {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.wrap {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="quiz">


    <form name="quiz" method="post" name="buttons" id="quiz" onsubmit="return false">
      <li>
        <div class="question">1. How many continents are there?</div>
      </li>
      <input id="answer" type="radio" name="group1" value="wrong"> 6<br>
      <input id="answer" type="radio" name="group1" value="wrong"> 8<br>
      <input id="answer" type="radio" name="group1" value="correct"> 7<br>
      <input id="answer" type="radio" name="group1" value="wrong"> 5
      <hr>


      <li>
        <div class="question">2. Where is France located?</div>
      </li>
      <div class="wrap">
        <input id="answer" type="radio" name="group2" value="correct">Europe<br>
        <input id="answer" type="radio" name="group2" value="wrong">Asia<br>
        <input id="answer" type="radio" name="group2" value="wrong">Antarctica<br>
        <input id="answer" type="radio" name="group2" value="wrong">North America
      </div>
      <hr>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I couldn't figure that out to save my life.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct , they are already middle aligned, but as per text your css is not visible in right manner so use lebels for text and align labels also